# Fragments not destroyed when recreate() activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a support library fragment that sends a network call, and `recreate()` the parent activity when it receives a specific network response. I can see that the activity does get recreated as I can see the `onCreate()` and `onDestroy()` are called.

But after the activity is recreated, the fragment is still there and it got stuck in a loop which keep recreating and making new fragments.

Here's part of the `onCreate()` of the activity:

```
    if (someLogic()) {
        fragmentA = new FragmentA();
        FragmentUtil.addFragment(getSupportFragmentManager(), fragmentA);
    } else {
        fragmentB = new FragmentB();
        FragmentUtil.addFragment(getSupportFragmentManager(), fragmentB);
    }
```

FragmentA is the one that does the network call, and FragmentB is the fragment that should be displayed after the `recreate()`. When I check the list of fragments with `getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments()` I see 1 instances of FragmentA, and 16 instances of FragmentB.

My question is why does this happen, and how do I fix it?

Comment: Can you show how you add the fragments and recreate the activity?
My guess is that you have to remove fragmentA before restarting the activity but I would need to see the code.
Btw why don't you simply replace fragmentA with fragmentB instead of restarting the activity?

Comment: Not that it is a concrete answer or that it is the ideal solution but you could check your fragment stack and only add a new fragment if you need to, else/or you could replace/refresh the current fragment

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Calling `recreate()` essentially causes the `Activity` to go through a configuration change. A configuration change causes both the `Activity` and its `Fragment`s to be destroyed and recreated. So your `Fragment`s should in fact be destroyed when this occurs (you can see for yourself by adding a `Log` message in your fragment's `onDestroy` method).

The fact that configuration changes cause fragments to be destroyed and created however *does not* mean that the `FragmentManager` will simply forget the fragments ever existed. The `FragmentManager` will still hold a reference to the newly created fragment after the configuration change occurs.

One thing you can do to prevent multiple fragments from being created is by doing something like this in your activity's `onCreate()`:

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
    // The Activity is being created for the first time, so create and
    // add new fragments.
} else {
    // Otherwise, the activity is coming back after being destroyed.
    // The FragmentManager will restore the old Fragments so we don't
    // need to create any new ones here.
}
```

Comment: anyway to explicitly not retain a fragment during recreation? I have a day/night mode layout setup and i've having some issues multiple copies of the fragment in memory

Comment: @spy you can remove the fragment manually before recreating the Activity, "mFragmentManager.beginTransaction().remove(mFragment).commit();".

Answer (score 8):

I had same situation as @spy wrote, recreating the `Activity` after Day/Night mode is changed. `Activity` had four `Fragments` which they get **restored** after `Activity.recreate()` is called, because `FragmentManager` saves them as @Alex Lockwood stated. But restoring and not adding `Fragments` after recreation does not help me because of some architectural reasons of project, i wanted them to disappear.

Solution is to delete `Fragments` from `FragmentManager` just before `Activity.recreate()`is called, in my case it is in `Activity.onStart()`:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

Fragment fragmentA = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("fragmentATag");
if(fragmentA != null) 
    fragmentTransaction.remove(fragment);
// Find and delete other Fragments

fragmentTransaction.commit(); // or commitAllowingStateLoss()

recreate();
```

This way you will not get `Fragments` restored when `Activity.onCreate()` is called.

Comment: another option is to call `super.onCreate(null);` on activity creation, however, I am not sure what other drawbacks it may have